# Dynamic ExpandableList Android - Populated with values from Web

Tags: android, dynamic, android-asynctask, expandablelistview

I am looking to create an Expandable List with values that I am receiving during a AsyncTask. Is it possible that I can put theses values in a list?

The list will be displayed in another view once a user presses a button.

Would it be similar to setting the text for a string? (Using .setText)

Android.

Answer (score 0):

Get the values from the Async task and put them in an array.
And set the Adapter of the list to this array.

The values will be displayed via the getChildView().